# General velocity function in terms of acceleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, velocity

Suppose $v(t)$ is a function describing variable velocity of a mass $m$. Then $m$ is accelerating, thus we should be able to describe $v(t)$ in terms of some $a(t)$ as follows: $$v(t) = v_0+ta(t)$$

However, if we differentiate $ta(t)$ we get $a(t) + ta'(t)$. So, unless acceleration is constant, we are not getting the desired result. Does this mean that $v(t) = v_0+at$ only for the special case of constant acceleration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that acceleration is the time derivative of velocity:

$$ a(t) = \frac{dv}{dt} $$

So to get the velocity we integrate both sides with respect to time:

$$ v = \int\,a(t)\,dt \tag{1}$$

If, and only if, $a(t)$ is a constant we can immediately do this integral to get:

$$ v = at + C $$

and the constant of integration $C$ is the speed when $t=0$, i.e. $C = v_0$, so we get the equation you started with:

$$ v = v_0 + at $$

So you're quite correct that we get this equation only if $a$ is a constant and not dependent on time. If $a$ has any time dependence then when we do the integral in equation (1) we'll get a more complicated result.

Comment: Yeh, old John Rennie is fast ;)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed.

Let $f: \mathbb R^n\mapsto \mathbb R^m \,.$ Then from Taylor's Theorem, $$f(x)~=~ f(x_0) + (\mathrm D f(x_0))(\Delta x) + \frac{(\mathrm D^2(f(x_0)))(\Delta x)^{\otimes 2}}{2!} + \ldots $$ assuming $f \in \mathrm C^\infty.$

Coming to the present context, $\mathbf x: \mathbb R\mapsto \mathbb R^3$

$$\dot {\mathbf x} =  \dot{\mathbf x}(t_0) + \ddot{\mathbf x} ~(t- t_0)$$ assumes the acceleration is constant in time.